# analyze convolution in spatial domain against multiplication in frequency domain

Tags: convolution, image-processing, fast-fourier-transform

Lets say I have a image of $NxN$ and a **separable** filter that I want to apply on it.
there are 2 ways to do that:
1. By convolution in spatial domain.
2. By multiplication in frequency domain.

I need to analyze which way is better (depands on A).

My calculations so far:

for the first way: naive convolution will take $(NxN)*(AxA)$ multiplication operations and $A*(NxN)$ addition operations. i.e. $O(N^2A^2)$.
Now, we can use the fact that the filter is separable:
For each cell in the image we can only multiply 2A cells of the filter.
We will get: $(NxN)*(2A)+O(2A)(NxN) = O(N^2A)$.

for the second way: we will do the operations in the frequency domain-
To calculate FFT of the image we will pay $O(NlogN)$.
To calculate FFT of the filter we will pay $O(NlogN)$ [I am not sure about that..].

Point-to-point multiplication of the filter and the image will cost $NxN$. 
Calculate inverse FFT of the result image will cost $O(NlogN)$.
Summing it up: $O(NlogN)$.

I guess that I have mistakes because in my result it is clear that the the second way is cheaper but I know that it depands on A.

can someone help me?

Comment: Write the exact equations and solve for the border A. For the second one, usually you do not need to compute the filter FFT in real time. You basically have FFT, NXN, IFFT.